# AWS Dynamodb throwing 500 error when inserting huge data in column

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, tcpdf

I am extracting text from a large PDF file ( 8 MB ) using the smalot PHP Library and storing it inside a PHP variable.

Problem arises when I try to insert this value in a column of my dynamodb table.

using the below code -

```
$path = DOCUMENT_PIC_PATH .'/'. $filename ;
    $this->sync_file_from_s3($path);

    $credentials = new \Aws\Credentials\Credentials(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET);
    $client = new \Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient([
        'region'  => 'us-west-2',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => $credentials
    ]);

    $filename = preg_replace('"\.pdf$"', '.png', $filename);
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser(); 
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile($path); 

    $text = $pdf->getText();  // store the text inside this variable
    $text  =  trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text));                       
    $text = $text ? strtolower($text) : ' ';   

    $pages = 0;         
    foreach ($pdf->getPages() as $page) {
    ++$pages;
    }

    $admin_id = $this->getLoggedInUserAdminId() ;

        $i  = 1;
        while ($i <= $pages ) {
            $result = $client->batchWriteItem([
                'RequestItems' => [ // REQUIRED
                    DYNAMODBTABLE => [
                        [
                            'PutRequest' => [
                                'Item' => [
                                    'title'=> array('S' => $title),
                                    'admin_id'=> array('N' => "$admin_id"),
                                    'document_id'=> array('N' => "$document_id"),
                                    'page_no'=> array('N' => "$i" ),
                                    'total_pages'=> array('N' => "$pages" ),
                                    **'text' => array('S' => $text),**
                                    'filesize' => array('N' => $filesize),
                                    'thumbnail' => array('S' => $filename),
                                    'airlineGroups' => array('SS' => $documentDataAirlines)
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
            $i++ ;
        }
```

Although the small ones are working smoothly and only the **big PDF files are causing the damage**.

I will be grateful if anybody specially from the amazon community can help me with a feasible  solution for this head aching problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may be hitting the DynamoDB Item Limit size, which is 400KB

> The maximum item size in DynamoDB is 400 KB, which includes both
>   attribute name binary length (UTF-8 length) and attribute value
>   lengths (again binary length). The attribute name counts towards the
>   size limit.

Source : [Limits in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-items)

Here are some recommendations form AWS to workaround this situation, as mentioned in [Best Practices for Storing Large Items and Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html)

> Amazon DynamoDB currently limits the size of each item that you store
>   in a table (see Limits in DynamoDB). If your application needs to
>   store more data in an item than the DynamoDB size limit permits, you
>   can try compressing one or more large attributes or breaking the item
>   into multiple items (efficiently indexed by sort keys). You can also
>   store the item as an object in Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon
>   S3) and store the Amazon S3 object identifier in your DynamoDB item.

Comment: But same PDF file  is working fine on other environment on a different dynamodb table.